# Given two positions `p1` and `p2`, how can I find a third position `p3` in the same direction of `p1 -> p2` and with distance of `d` of `p1`

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two positions `p1` and `p2`, how can I find a third position `p3` in the same direction of `p1 -> p2` and a minimum distance of `d`.

Here is a illustration to help understand:

[image]

Comment: This is just analytic geometry. Calculate the unit vector from p1 to p2, and extend it for distance d.

Comment: Any idea how I can extend it for the distance `d`?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the magnitude (length) of a vector? Given a vector, do you know how to generate a vector with the same direction, but, say, three times the length?

Comment: simple vector math `p2 = p3 + distance*(p1-p3)/|p1-p3|` where `|a|` means length of vector `a` so  in 3D `|a| = sqrt ( a.x*a.x + a.y*a.y +a.z*a.z )` for 2D just remove the `a.z` ...

Comment: @Beta, my current approach is similar to this. I calculate the magnitude and increases it sizes (multiply by 2) until it's bigger than `d`. However, this is hack and doesn't actually gives me the a point with the exact distance `d` from `p1`.

@Spektre, I only have `p1` and `p2`.

Answer (score 1):

You know how to calculate the magnitude of a vector such as s = |**p<sub>2</sub>** - **p<sub>1</sub>**| and you know how to scale a vector by a factor k, such as k = 2. So all you need is the correct factor to give a vector with magnitude d.

The factor you're looking for is k = d/s.